# Sort A Dictionary Alphabetically

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is not sorted alphabetically that looks like this:

```
dict = {'zebra': ['file1.txt'], 'alpha': ['file2.txt', 'file3.txt'], ...........}
```

I want to sort it alphabetically so the output is:

```
dict ={'alpha': ['file2.txt', 'file3.txt'],'zebra': ['file1.txt'],  ...........}
```

But from what I've seen online so far, their code for ordering it alphabetically loses the properties of a dictionary and either returns a list or it uses OrderedDict which is not the type I want.

A suggestion that made it a list was

```
sorteddict=sorted(dict.keys(), key=lambda x:x.lower())
```

But obviously that is not what I'm looking for

Can I somehow use sort on a dictionary while keeping its properties?

Answer (score 1):

You should not name your variable `dict` otherwist you won't be able to use the dictionary constructor.

```
dict1 = dict(sorted(dict1.items())
```